# How to specify which content scripts which will run on all_frames and which won't?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, manifest, frames

When specifying parameters in the manifest file of a chrome extension there is an option `all_frames`. This allows the content scripts to be embedded in all frames of a page or not.

An example of what I want to achieve is have a.js running with **all_frames=false** and b.js with `all_frames=true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `content_scripts` manifest property is an *array*, so you can define multiple content script specification objects:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["a.js"],
      "all_frames": false
    },

    {
      "matches": ["http://www.yahoo.com/*"],
      "js": ["b.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, it seems a bit stupid that I did not notice from the beginning!