# Open tab with button click using Chrome Tabs API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone have any advice on how I would open a new tab in google chrome, using the Chrome Tabs API. I've been trying to do this in my Google Chrome extension, like so

```
<form>
    Which page would you like to visit? <br />
    <input type="text" id="channel" name="channel" placeholder="url">
    <input type="button" value="button name" chrome.tabs.create="('#input from id="channel"')" />
</form>
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? (ignore the #input from id part, I know that won't work).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing `<input type="button" value="button name" chrome.tabs.create="('#input from id="channel"')" />` to `<input type="button" value="button name" onclick="chrome.tabs.create({url : document.getElementById('channel').value.toString})" />`. Used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862479/chrome-extension-create-new-tabchrome-tabs-create-and-executescript-in-new-ta)

Comment: @TheMintyMate That won't work in an extension, because "onclick" isn't allowed.  OP needs to remove all the javascript into a separate js file and load that with a script tag.

Comment: How would I set up the listener to identify that the button was clicked in popup.html though?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't HAVE to use chrome extension

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open(document.getElementById('channel').value,'_blank')" />
```

`_blank` is the argument needed to open on a new tab.

Comment: <form>
      Which page would you like to visit? <br />
      <input type="text" id="channel" name="channel" placeholder="https://www.google.com">
      <input type="button" value="button name" onclick="window.open(url, '_blank')" />
    </form>

Is what I have no, and it isn't working

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to mention that you want to use the actual url of the place you want to visit in place of the url. I'll edit accordingly